# How to capture and render an image from Play framework, Jquery Ajax, from Heroku

Tags: jquery, heroku, playframework, image-rendering

As the title states, I'm trying to get an image from my database to try an display on an external web page. Eventually I would like to use this for a mobile application that is run with PhoneGap.

```
renderBinary(member.profileImage.getFile());
```

(This is inside a member class)

```
public Blob profileImage;
```

So far, then I try to receive the image using ajax I get this: (note, this is like half a line of the 100 lines that I get)

�������"�����   ��?����������
���������
�3�!1AQa"q�2���B#$R�b34r��C%�S���cs5���&D�TdE£t6�U�e���u��F'�������������Vfv��������7GWgw���������5�!1AQaq"2����B#�R��3$b�r��CScs4�%���&5��D�T�dEU6te����u��F�������������Vfv��������'7GWgw����������?��^�[�'*��X���;+����#��u#Ѻ�zn���s���L�ʿ�m�Z%%�Z�P�n�W��&�6��}�G��
O�Q�k~1�y$\��Վ��ku���z�X�.�WSs�z��c}�f�������J��L���'ncO��E��K�z��V%7\���0���c`��/�?����A^���v��k�&�^�  i�s?ͳژM!+}Ula.~��˩w�g�؊�̻��Q��|���W��

So is there anyway that I might be able to convert this into Base64? Or even just something that I can use to place in an image tag on an html file?

Comment: http://www.lunatech-research.com/playframework-file-upload-blob

Comment: How are you fetching the image via ajax?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an encoding problem.

Are you storing a mimetype with the image, or alternatively, do you know the mime type ahead of time? What do your HTTP response headers look like on the AJAX? Based on what I see, you probably just need to include a mime type. Eg, for JPEG use `content-type: image/JPEG` in your response header.

Comment: I'll have to get back to you on this. This is quite an old project that I worked on in university. I'll let you know if I can find the code and have a look at it :)